# Using Variables in an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Here is a link to a list of variables that I am using from the US Census: http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc/variables.json

I do realize that you can already see the name of the state from the drop down, but my ultimate goal is to be able to select a state from the drop down and have the population and population density, along with the state ID value or the state name (I don't care at this point because I am frustrated :( )appear. I was experimenting with state name first before I moved onto pop or pop density.

What am I doing wrong? Debugger didn't really help me too much. The error message that I get is

> Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

In particular, here is the variable that I am using:

```
variables: {
STNAME: {
label: "State name",
concept: "Selectable Geographies"
},
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="title">
        <h1>United States Population Search</h1>
        <hr/>
    </section>
    <section id="inputArea">
        <form>
            <select id="inputBox">
                <option value="01">Alabama</option>
                <option value="02">Alaska</option>
                <option value="04">Arizona</option>
                <option value="05">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="06">California</option>
                <option value="08">Colorado</option>
                <option value="09">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="10">Delaware</option>
                <option value="11">District of Columbia</option>
                <option value="12">Florida</option>
                <option value="13">Georgia</option>
                <option value="15">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="16">Idaho</option>
                <option value="17">Illinois</option>
                <option value="18">Indiana</option>
                <option value="19">Iowa</option>
                <option value="20">Kansas</option>
                <option value="21">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="22">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="23">Maine</option>
                <option value="24">Maryland</option>
                <option value="25">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="26">Michigan</option>
                <option value="27">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="28">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="29">Missouri</option>
                <option value="30">Montana</option>
                <option value="31">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="32">Nevada</option>
                <option value="33">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="34">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="35">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="36">New York</option>
                <option value="37">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="38">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="39">Ohio</option>
                <option value="40">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="41">Oregon</option>
                <option value="42">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="44">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="45">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="46">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="47">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="48">Texas</option>
                <option value="49">Utah</option>
                <option value="50">Vermont</option>
                <option value="51">Virginia</option>
                <option value="53">Washington</option>
                <option value="54">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="55">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="56">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" class="searchButton"  value="Search"/>
            <hr/>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section class="searchResults">
        <div class="hiddenTemplates">
            <dl class="stateInformation">
                <dt><u>State ID Value:</u></dt>
                    <dd class="stateName"></dd>
                <dt><u>Population Amount:</u></dt>
                    <dd class="statePopulation"></dd>
                <dt><u>Population Density:</u></dt>
                    <dd class="statePopulationDensity"></dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="errorMessage">
                <p><b>Error Message: Something has gone wrong, try your search again.</b></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var data = { "variables": {
"for": {
  "label": "Census API FIPS 'for' clause",
  "concept": "Census API Geography Specification",
  "predicateType": "fips-for",
  "predicateOnly": true
},
"in": {
  "label": "Census API FIPS 'in' clause",
  "concept": "Census API Geography Specification",
  "predicateType": "fips-in",
  "predicateOnly": true
},
"STATE": {
  "label": "Total for US",
  "concept": "Selectable Geographies"
},
"NIM": {
  "label": "Net International Migration",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"STNAME": {
  "label": "State name",
  "concept": "Selectable Geographies"
},
"POP": {
  "label": "Resident population total",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"SUMLEV": {
  "label": "Geographic Summary Level",
  "concept": "Selectable Geographies"
},
"RESIDUAL": {
  "label": "Final residual for total pop",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"DIVISION": {
  "label": "Census Division Code",
  "concept": "Geographic Characteristics"
},
"DOM": {
  "label": "Net Domestic Migration of total Pop",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"DENSITY": {
  "label": "Population Density",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"BIRTHS": {
  "label": "Total Births",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"DATE": {
  "label": "Estimate Date",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "required": true,
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"REGION": {
  "label": "Census Region Code",
  "concept": "Geographic Characteristics"
},
"DEATHS": {
  "label": "Total Deaths",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
}
 }
};


//This function fills in the result,
//in our results box, this will give us the name of the US State
var showStateInformation = function(data){

    //var myTest = data.variables.STNAME;
    var label = data.variables.STNAME.label;

    //Puts the name of the state into the state name area
    //var nameOfState = $('.stateName');
    //nameOfState.text(stateSearch);
    //var result = $('.searchResults . hiddenTemplates .stateInformation');
    var nameOfState = $('.stateName');
    nameOfState.text(label);
    //in our results box, this will give us the population for that state
    //based on the Census Data
    //var statePopAmount = result.find('.statePopulation');
    //statePopAmount.text(population);
    //in our results box, this will give us the population density for that state
    //based on the Census Data
    //var statePopDensity = result.find('.statePopulationDensity');
    //statePopDensity.text(populationDensity);

}

//The error message
var showError = function(error){
        var errorElem = $('.searchResults .errorMessage');
        var errorText = '<p>' + error + '</p>';
        errorElem.append(errorText);
}

//This function retrieves the said data
//http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/population-estimates-and-projections.html
//US, State, and PR Total Population and Components of Change

var getStateInformation = function(stateID){
    //the parameters that we need to pass in our request to the US CENSUS API
    var request = {
        "get": "STNAME",
        "DATE": "6",
        "for": "state:" + stateID,

        "key": 'I was told not to post the key publicly online'
    }

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        data: request,
        url: "http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc",
        dataType: "json",
    })
    //What the function should do if successful
    /*.done(function(){
        var variables = $('#inputBox').val();
        showStateInformation(variables);
    })*/
    .done(showStateInformation)

    //What the function should do if it fails
    .fail(function(jqXHR, error){
        var errorElem = showError(error);
    })


}

$(document).ready(function() {

    /*Clicking the Search Button*/
    $('.searchButton').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var stateID = $('#inputBox').val();
        getStateInformation(stateID);

    })
})
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: I edited my post to include it.

Comment: How do you declare and initialize 'variables'?

Comment: variables come from that link that I posted. I thought once I sent something to the server, I didn't need to define anything because it was defined on the server and all I had to do was correctly label everything I was trying to return. I.e. variables.STNAME.label.   If you click that link at the very top, the US Census actually calls the parent(?) "variables"

Comment: emd you deleted your post. I was just getting ready to respond to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare and initialized your object properly

```
variables = {};
variables: {
label: "State name",
concept: "Selectable Geographies"
};
```

**EDIT**: It turned out you edit the question to make it more clear. So the data is fetch from the US Census API. The only thing you have to do is access the object property properly.
Assuming this is the data you fetch from the US Census:

```
var data = { "variables": {
"for": {
  "label": "Census API FIPS 'for' clause",
  "concept": "Census API Geography Specification",
  "predicateType": "fips-for",
  "predicateOnly": true
},
"in": {
  "label": "Census API FIPS 'in' clause",
  "concept": "Census API Geography Specification",
  "predicateType": "fips-in",
  "predicateOnly": true
},
"STATE": {
  "label": "Total for US",
  "concept": "Selectable Geographies"
},
"NIM": {
  "label": "Net International Migration",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"STNAME": {
  "label": "State name",
  "concept": "Selectable Geographies"
},
"POP": {
  "label": "Resident population total",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"SUMLEV": {
  "label": "Geographic Summary Level",
  "concept": "Selectable Geographies"
},
"RESIDUAL": {
  "label": "Final residual for total pop",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"DIVISION": {
  "label": "Census Division Code",
  "concept": "Geographic Characteristics"
},
"DOM": {
  "label": "Net Domestic Migration of total Pop",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"DENSITY": {
  "label": "Population Density",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"BIRTHS": {
  "label": "Total Births",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"DATE": {
  "label": "Estimate Date",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "required": true,
  "predicateType": "int"
},
"REGION": {
  "label": "Census Region Code",
  "concept": "Geographic Characteristics"
},
"DEATHS": {
  "label": "Total Deaths",
  "concept": "Estimate Variables",
  "predicateType": "int"
}
 }
};
```

The way to access it is:

```
var label = data.variables.STNAME.label
```

The way you are doing now is a bit wrong. It should be something like this.

```
var showStateInformation = function(data){

  var myTest = data.variables.STNAME;

// OMIT THE REST OF THE CODE
}
```

If the data is still in type of string, you need to parse it first. But I strongly suggest you do it before calling this function and return a proper object. But for now, try to check first

```
if (typeof data == 'string') {
  data = JSON.parse(data}
}
```

**EDIT**: It turned out the url used in JQuery is different with the API url in the text. That is another bugs found:

```js
var getStateInformation = function(stateID){
//the parameters that we need to pass in our request to the US CENSUS API
var request = {
"get": "STNAME",
"DATE": "6",
"for": "state:" + stateID,

"key": 'I was told not to post the key publicly online'
}

$.ajax({

type: "GET",
url: "http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc/variables.json"
})
//What the function should do if successful
.done(function(data){
console.log(data.variables.STNAME);
})

//What the function should do if it fails
.fail(function(jqXHR, error){
var errorElem = showError(error);
})


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just happened to refresh the page and see comments.

Comment: Okay, I will let you know how this goes.

Comment: I am still getting an error message, but maybe this is because of the way I have edited my code. I posted the edited version, based on your comment, above so you can see my edit. The error message is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'STNAME' of undefined"

Comment: @LunchBox Can you check the typeof the data? Because you need to parse it first before you can use it as an object. When it first came to you, it is just a plain string.

Comment: You edited your post to talk about parsing data. Should I put this in the ".done" area at the bottom?

Comment: @LunchBox For now, just put in showStateInformation. That is the callback for done. So kinda no diff

Comment: That's what I thought and that's what I did. I put it at the very beginning of the "showStateInformation" function, before "var label = . . . " I am still getting the same error message about STNAME

Comment: data = [Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]  This is what I got when I put in debugger after the if statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98752/discussion-between-geckob-and-lunchbox).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message 'Cannot read property 'label' of undefined' because you are trying to access a property (label) of an object which doesn't exist (variables.STNAME). Essentially this means that the structure of the variables object is not what you have assumed it is.

The easiest thing to do would be to print out what comes back from your ajax call by adding:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(variables))
```

at the start of the showStateInformation function.

In the alert dialog you should be able to see the structure of the object that was sent back from the API and can therefore construct code to access the object members properly.